# Запрет доступа по IP

Tags: .htaccess, php

```
allow from all
deny from 145.186.14.122
```

Заход с данного IP запрещен.
Подскажите как задавать маски (* у меня не срабатывает).
Еще один вопрос  связан 
    AllowOverride All в файле httpd.conf

Если задать припустим AllowOverride Indexes ,тогда условие файла не должно сработать,а это не так.Сервер перезапускал.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну тут как вам угодно. Можно так

```
deny from 145.186.14.0/24
```

Можно так:

```
deny from 145.186.14.0/255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Благодарен